# Menu hiding behind Nivo Slider

Tags: css

I tried z-index, it's not working for some reason. How can I fix it ?

http://goo.gl/VJKWh

```
#menu {
background-color:#FFF;
height:30px;
border:0;
border-top:2px solid #8BD2E4;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 6px 0 6px;
z-index:9998;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add;

```
z-index:9999;
```

to "#blog-menu ul"

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
.sub-menu{
    z-index:999;
}
```